# i still can't connect gt-s5360 Samsung phone to windows 7 PC

Tags: usb

i still can't connect gt-s5360 Samsung phone to windows 7 PC but it charging i can't get "connect to pc" option and  i can connect another Samsung phone to PC with same usb cable

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the model of your phone, you may not be able to get the "Connect to PC" dialog. This is normal behavior.

Troubleshoot:

- Since you can connect another phone to your PC, you probably have the
  correct drivers (since Samsung uses a universal USB driver which you
  can download [**here**](http://www.mediafire.com/?7srv709j7nkivj0)), but I would try to install it just in
  case (it doesn't hurt to try).
- Try disabling **USB Debugging** under **Settings > Developer Settings**.
- Try enabling **Settings > Wireless and Network > USB Settings > Ask on connection**.